# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-sortable

I am getting this error when trying to use ui-sortable.

jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**The meaning of your error is** : `$this.draggable('enable');` is called before `$this.draggable();.`

Check the execution flow of your program : make sure that you have indeed initialized the plugin (e.g : called `$this.draggable();`) before trying to do anything with it.

Comment: I have used angular-ui-sortable for sorting and dropping. So, have you idea, how we can use this $this.draggable();?